# Determine power usage for specific timeframe

Tags: battery-life, diagnostics

Under battery usage, I can see “battery usage since full charge,” broken down by app (and, if toggled on, non-app phone processes). I’d like to see that breakdown but in a more specific timeframe (and, if possible, prior to my last full charge).

The phone is a Motorola “moto g power” running Android version 11, security update June 1, 2021.

#### Context:

Last night, I went to bed with my phone at 49% (I checked because had been a bit since I charged it); this morning it was dead. The battery usage graph showed four days of steadily-declining battery, to just under 50% as I saw it last night, followed by a nose-dive to 0% in a few hours. The breakdown of usage showed about a third used by Firefox (makes sense, that’s the overwhelming majority of my usage of the phone), about a third used by “mobile network standby” (which makes little sense, I have pretty good signal), and the rest divided among a bunch of different things.

My assumption is that Firefox was the dominant usage over most of those four days, and mobile network standby is what caused the precipitous drop last night. However, I don’t *know* that—it could be that mobile network standby is always draining my battery more than I think it is, and something *else* (probably increased usage by Firefox?) last night caused the drain.

#### Question:

Is there any way to get that same battery usage breakdown, but for just those hours last night, rather than “since last full charge”? For that matter, I have since charged the phone, so now it displays no data since it just charged—is the record I described above just gone now?

Comment: I am afraid the data you are looking for is lost. Battery stats are re set when you face [shutdown at 0%](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power) or when you  [charge to 90%](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193416/what-resets-the-battery-stats)

Comment: @beeshyams The data I describe in this question came after the phone died at 0%, charged some, and restarted, so I know the first half of that is untrue (now, for this phone, anyway). Even if the data is gone, though, I would want to know for the future.